# WPF GRID to GRID drag and drop

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls, grid, wpf-controls

I am trying to find a way to drag and drop between two grids(NOT datagrids). Both grids have 3 columns and the second grid gets populated based on whats dropped from first grid and the rows on second grid are generated dynamically. First grid has custom controls as icons. I am unable to get the items on the first grid as row/column co-ordinates but the mouse event handler gives me the (x,y) point co-ordinatels. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then the main problem you have is to get the control under your mouse cursor. You can get it by using either [UIElement.InputHitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) or [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx) to get that control / visual. Also do check out this article on MSDN: [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) - it is a well-written explanation of this process with examples.